# Angular ejecuto mas de una vez un subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, programación-reactiva

Desde el ngOnInit se esta haciendo una subscripcion y dentro se hace un llamado a otro metodo que tambien tiene una subscripcion, esta segunda subscripcion se esta ejecutando 3 veces cuando se inicia el componente de angular

```javascript
ngOnInit() {
  this.servicio.funcionUno.subscribe(res=> {   
    this.cargarDependencias();
  });
}

cargarDependencias(){ 
  this.servicio.obtenerDatos(req).subscribe(res => {
    this.stages = res.data;   
  });
}
```

Comment: Eso significa que que el observable emite 3 veces datos. Si no es lo que esperas, comprueba qué hace `this.servicio.obtenerDatos(req)` y por qué emite 3 veces. En cualquier caso, siempre puedes des-suscribirte de ese observable tras recibir datos por primera vez

Answer (score 0):

Te sugeriría utilizar el método toPromise() en vez de Subscribe. De esta manera sólo obtendrás una vez el resultado.

Comment: Transformar observables a promesas porque no sabes qué está pasando no me parece un buen consejo. Angular está fuertemente ligado a la librería rxjs y tiene sus razones.

Comment: implemente en el subscribe un take(1) y agregue un ngOnDestroy y ya solamente hace una petición. Muchas gracias